# Select filter doesn't work with cellTemplate, angular ui-grid

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm working with angular ui-grid library and faced with the problem. I cannot understand how to apply filter for cell with multiple values.
Columns category has an inner array, which I display thru cellTemplate like this

```
cellTemplate: "<div ng-repeat='item in row.entity[col.field]'>{{item.name}}</div>"
```

also in category column I have select filter with dynamic array, which I'm getting thru services

```
 filter: {
                type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                selectOptions: $scope.categories
            },
```

where $scope.categories comes from

```
 lovServices.categories().then(function (result) {
                angular.forEach(result, function (value) {
                    $scope.categories.push({
                        value: value.id,
                        label: value.name
                    });
                });
            });
```

But when I'm selecting any category filter it shows me an empty grid, I understand that grid filter cannot find any value, but the reason of it I cannot understand.

Could anybody help me to find my mistake? I appreciate any help.

Code:

```
    app.controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, $http, uiGridConstants, lovServices) {

        $scope.categories = [];

        // Get Grid Data
        var getData = function () {
            lovServices.eventTypes()
                .then(function (response) {
                    //Initial Data
                    $scope.gridOptions.data = response;
                });
        };
        var getOptions = function () {
            lovServices.categories().then(function (result) {
                angular.forEach(result, function (value) {
                    $scope.categories.push({
                        value: value.id,
                        label: value.name
                    });
                });
            });
        };

        // Ui-Grid Options
        $scope.gridOptions = {
            enableFiltering: true,
            rowHeight: 60
        };

        // Ui-Grid Columns
        $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
            {
                displayName: 'Name',
                field: 'name',
                sort: {
                    direction: uiGridConstants.ASC
                }
            },
            {
                field: 'description',
            },
            {
                field: 'category',
                enableSorting: false,
                filter: {
                    type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
                    selectOptions: $scope.categories
                },
                cellTemplate: "<div ng-repeat='item in row.entity[col.field]'>{{item.name}}</div>"
            }
        ];

        $scope.gridOptions.onRegisterApi = function (gridApi) {
            $scope.gridApi = gridApi;

        };

        //Get data
        getData();
        getOptions();

    });
```

[This is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9woKziC9qHItaGfAP8kw?p=preview) with my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the data you are filtering against is an array, and not a flat value, it must be compared through iteration.

That is to say, a anonymous function must be supplied as the `condition` key to the filter object, in order to iterate through the column values and figure out which one matches the search term.

[Documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef#properties_filter)

Example:

```js
filter: {
    condition: function(searchTerm, cellValue, row, column) {
        var filtered = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < cellValue.length; i++) {
            filtered = cellValue[i].id === searchTerm;
            if (filtered) {
                break;
            }
        }
        return filtered;
    },
    type: uiGridConstants.filter.SELECT,
    selectOptions: $scope.categories
},
```

[Updated plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bC5Qvyoj2zBHwX2xepxo?p=preview)

Comment: The condition, that's it I couldn't understand how to apply, I have tried to impact on it thru for loop in filterChanged at the grid core but did't get any success. Thank you a lot for a help! I have to read docs more careful.